# Share a class created in a custom DLL through WCF service

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I have a dll that contains a class called A.

I reference it in my WCF library project.

I create an operation contract as follows:

```
[OperationContract]
public AContainer getA();
```

I create a datacontract as follows

```
[DataContract]
public class AContainer
{
 private A _a;
 public A Val
 {
   get{return _a;}
   set{_a = value;}
 }
}
```

However the service will not compile giving the following error:

> Error: Cannot obtain Metadata from
>   localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/ARGUSService/Service1/mex If this
>   is a Windows (R) Communication Foundation service to which you have
>   access, please check that you have enabled metadata publishing at the
>   specified address.  For help enabling metadata publishing, please
>   refer to the MSDN documentation at
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=65455.WS-Metadata Exchange
>   Error    URI:
>   localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/ARGUSService/Service1/mex
>   Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved:
>   'localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/ARGUSService/Service1/mex'.
>   `Receivera:InternalServiceFault`An exception was thrown in a call to a WSDL export
>   extension:
>   System.ServiceModel.Description.DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior
>   contract: http://tempuri.org/:IARGUSType
>   'WackStr.ARGUS.TRAFCO.CRM.TRAFCODetail' cannot be serialized. Consider
>   marking it with the DataContractAttribute attribute, and marking all
>   of its members you want serialized with the DataMemberAttribute
>   attribute.  If the type is a collection, consider marking it with the
>   CollectionDataContractAttribute.  See the Microsoft .NET Framework
>   documentation for other supported types.   at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.DataContractCriticalHelper.ThrowInvalidDataContractException(String
>   message, Type type)   at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.DataContractCriticalHelper.CreateDataContract(Int32
>   id, RuntimeTypeHandle typeHandle, Type type)   at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.DataContractCriticalHelper.GetDataContractSkipValidation(Int32
>   id, RuntimeTypeHandle typeHandle, Type type)   at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSet.GetDataContract(Type
>   clrType)   at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSet.GetMemberTypeDataContract(DataMember
>   dataMember)   at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSet.AddClassDataContract(ClassDataContract
>   classDataContract)   at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSet.InternalAdd(XmlQualifiedName
>   name, DataContract dataContract)   at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSet.Add(Type type)   at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.XsdDataContractExporter.Export(Type type)
>   at
>   System.ServiceModel.Description.MessageContractExporter.ExportType(Type
>   type, String partName, String operationName, XmlSchemaType&
>   xsdType)   at
>   System.ServiceModel.Description.DataContractSerializerMessageContractExporter.ExportBody(Int32
>   messageIndex, Object state)   at
>   System.ServiceModel.Description.MessageContractExporter.ExportMessage(Int32
>   messageIndex, Object state)   at
>   System.ServiceModel.Description.MessageContractExporter.ExportMessageContract()
>   at
>   System.ServiceModel.Description.DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior.System.ServiceModel.Description.IWsdlExportExtension.ExportContract(WsdlExporter
>   exporter, WsdlContractConversionContext contractContext)   at
>   System.ServiceModel.Description.WsdlExporter.CallExtension(WsdlContractConversionContext
>   contractContext, IWsdlExportExtension
>   extension)System.Runtime.Serialization.InvalidDataContractExceptionAn
>   exception was thrown in a call to a WSDL export extension:
>   System.ServiceModel.Description.DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior
>   contract: http://tempuri.org/:IARGUS   at
>   System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceMetadataBehavior.MetadataExtensionInitializer.GenerateMetadata()
>   at
>   System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceMetadataExtension.EnsureInitialized()
>   at
>   System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceMetadataExtension.WSMexImpl.GatherMetadata(String
>   dialect, String identifier)   at
>   System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceMetadataExtension.WSMexImpl.Get(Message
>   request)   at SyncInvokeGet(Object , Object[] , Object[] )   at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object
>   instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)   at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc&
>   rpc)   at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc&
>   rpc)   at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage41(MessageRpc&
>   rpc)   at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage4(MessageRpc&
>   rpc)   at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc&
>   rpc)   at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage3(MessageRpc&
>   rpc)   at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage2(MessageRpc&
>   rpc)   at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage11(MessageRpc&
>   rpc)   at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage1(MessageRpc&
>   rpc)   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean
>   isOperationContextSet)System.InvalidOperationExceptionHTTP
>   GET Error    URI:
>   localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/ARGUSService/Service1/mex
>   There was an error downloading
>   'localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/ARGUSService/Service1/mex'.
>   The request failed with HTTP status 400: Bad Request.

Comment: It doesn't look like the error is related to the code you have posted, it is saying that it cannot serialise a type called WackStr.ARGUS.TRAFCO.CRM.TRAFCODetail, please post the code associated with that type.  FYI If you wanted to serialise the Val property of the A class then you should decorate it with `[DataMember]` attribute.

Comment: The error message pretty clearly says what you have to do. `Consider marking it with the DataContractAttribute attribute, and marking all of its members you want serialized with the DataMemberAttribute attribute.` Did you do so?